# Adding multiple folders with Add-PnPFolder appears impossible in a Runbook

Tags: azure-automation

I have some simple code to add a couple of folders to a SharePoint Site library. Locally it runs smoothly in seconds, but in a runbook the same code runs increasingly slower, resulting in getting the runbook suspended. Looking at the error messages, it seems that somehow it even goes into a loop of repeating commands. Max. 3 folders are created. In Azure and local I have the same module ( PnP.Powershell 1.2.0)
Any tips are very welcome.

```
$dcSharePointRootUrl = "https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/"
$SiteUrl = "13Test"
$credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "XXX" ;
$targetSite = $dcSharePointRootUrl + $SiteUrl
Connect-PnPOnline -Url  $targetSite -Credentials $credential 
$targetFolder =  "/sites/"+ $SiteUrl + "/Shared Documents"
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Technical proposal" -Folder $targetFolder
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Procurement" -Folder $targetFolder
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Engineering" -Folder $targetFolder
Add-PnPFolder -Name "Commercial proposal" -Folder $targetFolder
```

> Error messages: Add-PnPFolder : A file or folder with the name
> https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/13Test/Shared Documents/Technical
> proposal already exists. At line:16 char:1 + Add-PnPFolder -Name
> "Technical proposal" -Folder $targetFolder +
>
> ```
> CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPFolder], ServerException +
> FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.AddFolder
> ```

Answer (score 0):

a runbook needs a var, like :
$dummy = Add-PnPFolder -Name "Technical proposal" -Folder $targetFolder